# How can i make mandatory to click one of the toggle buttons in react form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How can i make mandatory to click one of the toggle buttons in react form? When the user presses the submit button, I want to show an error if the toggle has not clicked one of the buttons. In short, I want to make it necessary to click one of the toggle buttons. How can I do that?

[image: toggle]

**Component sample**

```
   class MyForm extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (

          <form>
            <h1>Please click one of them</h1>
              <ButtonGroup toggle required>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="radio" defaultChecked value="1">
                    Active
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
                    Radio
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="radio" value="3">
                    Radio
                </ToggleButton>
             </ButtonGroup>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
          </form>

        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you save the value of the buttons to state, you could disable the submit button based on that state. You could also use onClick event handler on the button, or an onSubmit handler on the form to check if all needed values are entered before you let the user submit the form. You can also add validation to the form and use validation events to set props on the buttons etc. There are quite a few ways you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of it using a boolean value that is stored in state. I would use the React hook useState to do something like :

```
const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState({

clicked: false

})
```

make a handleSubmit function that will check the value of "clicked" when the form is submitted:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
e.preventDefault()

if (isClicked) {
//submit the form

} else {
 //this will place an error warning in the browser console
 console.error("no selection made")
//this will tell the user that a selection was not made
 alert("You must select one!")
return false
}
```

then, place an onChange event on each of the radio buttons that will set clicked to true, when the user clicks on that button.

```
<ToggleButton onChange={() => setClicked({clicked: true})} type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Radio</ToggleButton>
```

finally, add an onClick event on the submit button that will fire the handleSubmit function

```
<Button onClick={() => return handleSubmit()} variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

If handleSubmit returns false, then the form will not submit.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the value of the toggle button in the state. That way you'll know if a user has clicked the button.

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);

         this.state = {
          clicked: false,
        };
      }

     isClicked(){
     this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})

}
submitFunc(e){

e.preventDefault()

if(this.state.clicked){
// Do what ever you want
}else {
// Create an error msg
}

}



      render() {
        return (

          <form onSubmit={this.submitFunc}>
            <h1>Please click one of them</h1>
              <ButtonGroup toggle required>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="radio" defaultChecked value="1" onChange={this.isClicked}>
                    Active
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
                    Radio
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton type="radio" name="radio" value="3">
                    Radio
                </ToggleButton>
             </ButtonGroup>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" >
                Submit
            </Button>
          </form>

        );
      }
    }
```

Add the onChange event to all the radio buttons